# How to use cv2.split and cv2.merge on multiple images?

Tags: python, list, numpy, opencv

I am aware of the cv2 functions split() and merge().
I would like some help in using this function to split multiple images in a list. I have a list containing images. The images are all numpy arrays.
They are in the YCrCb format, basically a 3-channel format.

I would like to split each image into Y, Cr, Cb channels using cv2.split()

I am trying to run a for loop like this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(imgSet):
    imageChannel.append(cv2.cvtColor(item, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB))
for index_, item_ in enumerate(imageChannel):
    Y, Cr, Cb = cv2.split(item_)
```

This is not working. It returns one single Y-channel rather than the 12(total images in the list) Y-channels for each image.

EDIT: In other words I have numpy array of shape `(12,224,224,3)` where there are 12 images, each of size 224x224 and 3 color channels.
I would like to access the channels and split them using cv2.

My goal is to split every image in the list into the 3 channels.
Please do help.

Answer (score 0):

`Y`, `Cr`, and `Cb` are individual variables, and your loop repeatedly overwrites them.

```
for index, item in enumerate(imgSet):
    imageChannel.append(cv2.cvtColor(item, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB))
Y = [None]*12
Cr = [None]*12
Cb = [None]*12
for index_, item_ in enumerate(imageChannel):
    Y[index_], Cr[index_], Cb[index_] = cv2.split(item_)
```